# MacOS Chrome default search is redirected to yahoo

Tags: macos, google-chrome, search, hijack

The behavior looks like this:

1. when I search "baby" with my default search engine google.
2. I can see browser address bar shows "https://www.google.com.hk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JjV5WZ--N8TU8AfqgqII#q=baby"
3. And then after 1 or 2 seconds, it redirects to "https://hk.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?hspart=blp&hsimp=yhs-default&type=hmp_060_695_0&p=baby&rnd=1196689346&param1=sid%3D695%3Aaid%3D060%3Aver%3D0%3Atm%3D-1%3Asrc%3Dhmp%3Alng%3Den%3Aitype%3De%3Auip%3D1997106063%3Aup%3DYmFieQ%253D%253D"

I have tried below methods, but none of them works

- Reset default search engine to google
- Delete all search engines and create a new one with google search (https://www.google.com/#q=%s)
- Clean chrome extensions
- Clear /Libiary/Internet Plugins
- Reset Chrome
- Reinstall Chrome

I also tried below methods, which could be one of the temp solutions:

- Switch to Incognito window;
- Logout from Chrome;

Any idea about this?

==
After successfully clean the folder /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 1/Extensions/bfkmdpfljdpopbemfaelnflapafbflgn, it comes back again after two days.

So when I my chrome has the redirect issue, the folder contents looks like:

[image]

After I clean it, it looks like:

[image]

So I guess there must some virus either comes from my computer or from Chrome.
After some check, I find a non-removable extension:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the finally solution for this.
There is a extension named "Plugins Button" installed in chrome with super permission that you can not remove it.

Step1:
Quit Chrome;

Step2:

> $ rm -rf /Users/$NAME/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile $NUMBER/Extensions/bfkmdpfljdpopbemfaelnflapafbflgn/
>
> $ rm -rf
>   ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ $NUMBER/Sync\
>   Extension\ Settings/bfkmdpfljdpopbemfaelnflapafbflgn/

Step3:

Open "System Preferences" and click Profiles, you will find a weird profile named "your name". By taking a look at the detail, it contains the exact keyword "bfkmdpfljdpopbemfaelnflapafbflgn", delete the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating another user and see if it persists there.

What about Safari or Firefox?  Whether they are infected or not, the answer narrows the problem.

Check your DNS; perhaps it was hijacked.  8.8.8.8 is Google's Public DNS and will help if it's allowed in HK.  For a friendly trustworthy network, just setting DHCP-based DNS will usually work.

See if https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/ will kill it.

Try booting to a Linux LiveCD to see if it's environmental.  (Probably not this, but it's worth a look if nothing else works.)

Comment: After scan computer with Malwarebytes: I found this one "2017-07-29 09:03:24 :  Removing Extension Item: /Users/Joshua/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Extensions/bfkmdpfljdpopbemfaelnflapafbflgn". Now it works fine!!! It's a pity that I didn't take a look of file content before deleting it.